# Webview android 6.0 não carrega mapa com imagem

Tags: android, android-webview

Tenho uma aplicativo que recebe as configurações de js, html, css através do WebView, para criar um mapa offline.

No android 4.4 funciona corretamente. No android 6.0 não aparece nenhum conteúdo.

Realizo a chamada atraves do assets

```
webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/map.html");
```

Coloquei também as permissões no AndroidManifest.

**EDIT1**

O problema está ocorrendo no caminho para encontrar as imagens.
As permissões estavam certas.

```
webview.loadUrl("javascript:loadImg('/storage/14F0-C537/www')");
```

Mas o endereçamento do SdCard utilizado tem q ser alterado.

Comment: Quais permissões você colocou no AndroidManifest?

Comment: Colocamos permissoes de Internet, Acess_Fine_location, Acess_Coarse_Location, Read_External_Storage, Write_External_Storage

Answer (score 1):

A partir do Android 5.0 as permissões são solicitadas sob demanda, ou seja, o desenvolvedor precisa solicitar as permissões no momento em que irá usar. Pode está acontecendo isto, vai nas configurações do aplicativo e verifica se todas as permissões foram aceitas.

Comment: Pelas configurações do aplicativo, todas as permissões foram aceitas.
A minha duvida seria, sempre q acessar o aplicativo essas permissões deveram ser refeitas?

Comment: Não, as permissões só precisam ser aceitas uma vez pelo usuário